# ¿Cómo podría obtener el nombre del mes en lugar de su número? ejemplo 11 de 02 a 11 de Febrero

Tags: java, android-studio, date

Tengo este código pero solo me da el número del mes, el formato que tiene es [DIA] [MES] [AÑO]...
Aqui empezamos declarando los elementos que son dos TextView donde se visualizan los datos. xml

```
    vt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview2);
    ms = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);

    //objeto método clase

    Time today=new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    
    //Fecha actual
    today.setToNow();
    
    //Variables int
    int dia=today.monthDay;
    int mes=today.month;
    int ano=today.year;

    //Al mes se le suma +1, porque la clase time nos da siempre un mes atrasado

    mes=mes+1;
    vt.setText("" + dia + "  de   "+ mes);
    ms.setText(""+ano);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes traducirlo usando la clase `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
vt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview2);
ms = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);
// fecha actual
Date fecha = new Date();
// idioma actual del dispositivo
Locale idioma = Locale.getDefault();
String diaYMes = (new SimpleDateFormat("d 'de' MMMM", idioma)).format(fecha);
// "y" son los 4 digitos. Si sólo necesitas los 2 últimos usa "yy"
String anio = (new SimpleDateFormat("y", idioma)).format(fecha);
vt.setText(diaYMes);
ms.setText(anio);
```